# Undefined method 'presigned_post' aws-sdk gem Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to implement direct uploading to S3 via the `aws-sdk` gem. For some reason when trying to create the uploaded URL with the `presigned_post` method I get an error `undefined method 'presigned_post' for nil:NilClass`. Here's my setup so far:

**aws.rb**

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-2',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
})

S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'])
```

**uploads_controller.rb**

```
def set_s3_direct_post
  @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')
end
```

I beleive it might have something to do with how the `S3_BUCKET` is called, but I've tried it several different ways and it comes back with the same error each time.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, I ran into this same issue, and it turned out that the order of my initializers was off and my bucket.presigned_post was trying to execute on a null object (bucket). Take a [look at this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files), and see if it doesn't help you.